# How to get PHP to match textbox with corresponding checkbox from a form

Tags: php

Basically, I have about 700 customers in a database and I show them in a page with a loop, which goes through of all 700 customers. This loop adds a **checkbox** next to each customer, so you can select which one of them you want to go onto the next days schedule, on average this will be about 30 customers.

This is my form:

```php
<table>
<tr>
    <td class="search_result_fullname"><?php echo $row['fullname']; ?></td>
    <td class="search_result_price">&pound;<input type="text" name="price[]" value="<?php echo $price; ?>" class="schedule_price"></td>
    <td class="search_result_phone"><a href="tel:<?php echo $phone; ?>"><?php echo $phone; ?></a></td>
    <td class="search_result_checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="customerid[]" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="5"><input type="text" name="remarks[]" placeholder="Remarks" class="remarks"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Once this form is submitted, then it reloads the page and I have a `if(isset($_POST['add'])){` in place. I've tried various different loops and I cant for the life of me work out how to do it.

So, the form is submitting an array of only **checkboxs** that are checked. If I call `print_r($_POST['customerid']);` to verify it shows that this is working as expected. Then, if i select customer `50` and `51`, then it should return an array with just those two.

Now the problem is that I also want to get the correct price value for each customer (`50` and `51`), but the array for `$_POST['price']` is submitting the price for all 700 customers. How do I get the price to correspond to the correct customers that I've checked?

Any support is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set up the `price` array to be indexed by customer IDs:

```
<input type="text" name="price[<?=$row['id']?>]" value="<?=$price?>" class="schedule_price">
```

... and then reference prices by customer IDs:

```
$customerIds = $_POST['customerid'];
$prices = $_POST['price'];

foreach ($customerIds as $customerId) {
  $price = $prices[$customerId];
}
```

Comment: You can't match checkboxes in the first way, because unchecked boxes aren't sent to the server. That's why the indexes get out of sync.

Comment: @Barmar Oh I see, yes.

Comment: Thank you showdev, worked perfectly. You have no idea how many hours and frustration that has given me!